# How can I turn my python script off from the terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, pickle

I have just made a script that I want to turn off from the terminal, but instead of just ending it I want it to pickle a file. Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do.  Can you post some code?

Comment: What do you mean by turning off?

Comment: @fiacre I've already written a script I have a for loop running but I want to be able to stop the for loop and turn it off. but everytime I turn the script off I want it to pickle a file.

Comment: @alinikneshan terminate the script from the terminal but it needs to pickle a file before it closes the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at how [signals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) works.

You can basically make your script wait for a signal on QUIT:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from signal import *
from time import sleep

def process_quit(signum, frame):
    # Do your pickle thing here
    print('Exiting...')


signal(SIGQUIT, process_quit)

while 1:
    print('Working hard')
    sleep(0.5)
```

You can also register an handler with `atexit`:

```
import atexit

def exit_handler():
    print 'My application is ending!'

atexit.register(exit_handler)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I didn't ask my question as best as I could of don, I used atexit but I'll be looking in to signals also, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Check atexit() 
Add a function and decorate it with atexit